# DataSift and GoogleBigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been trying to export data to a google bigquery dataset from datasift, but except for 4 empty rows, no other relevant data has been pushed.
I followed instruction from this link: http://dev.datasift.com/docs/push/connectors/bigquery. Not sure if it's the csdl code that I used the cause.
For example I configured a stream using:
wikipedia.title contains "Audi".
The live preview has no output. Also, the only data sources that I've set as active are Interaction and Wikipedia.
Please let me know what may be the reason for this. At the end of every stream recording I don't see any changes, expect the creation of the table mentioned in the destination with 4 empty rows(some row have null values, and interaction.type is ds_verify).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you still struggling with this, or did you manage to resolve the issue? The 4 empty rows are typical of every DataSift to BigQuery Push  subscription - they are created during the validation and setup process.